# unable to fetch data as Post when Sending it as Post From IOS NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

this is the snippet to my Code, i am sending the code to a PHP page, but when i do print_r($_POST); i get empty Array, but when i do  print_r($_GET) i get the variable which i am using to post the data i.e **name** but it also is empty, can any 1 sort out what i am doing wrong here

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnFetchData1:(id)sender {
//    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/adi/adnan.php?name=%@", [self.txtName text]];
      NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/adi/adnan.php"];
     NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",@"adnan"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        _receivedData=[NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        //something bad happened
    }
}

#pragma NSUrlConnectionDelegate Methods

-(void)connection:(NSConnection*)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if (_receivedData == NULL) {
        _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [_receivedData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: responseData length:(%d)", _receivedData.length);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[_receivedData length]);

    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);

    NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
    responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];

    [self.lblData setText:responseText];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created `postLength` but never used it, try this it might solve it:

```
//create URL for the request
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/adi/adnan.php"];

//Post data
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",@"adnan"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

//the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

//Bind the request with Post data
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: still no change. I am still able to get data via print_r($_GET) but not print_r($_POST)

Comment: see my update avoid ASCII encoding if you can, you don't want to take that risk. other than that I see no other problem with your code, you sure the issue is not on the PHP server?